# Why a cubic plane curve meets a line three times?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Can someone explain to me why a cubic curve in a projective plane always meets a line three times?

Comment: Have you read the proof of/are you familiar with Bézout's theorem?

Comment: This may help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_theorem

Comment: Thx. I got it now. I'm new to algebraic geometry.

Answer (score 3):

Consider changing the coordinates so that the line in question is the $x$ axis.
Then you are just looking for the roots of a cubic equation. If you are working over an algebraically closed field then there will be three roots.

Comment: I like this answer best. Bézout's theorem is important to know, and certainly answers this question, but in this case --- intersecting with a _line_ --- it is overkill.